Is there supposed to be a black ring in a toilet supply valve?
My valve wasn’t shutting so I tried the plastic stem replacement kit. Seemed to go well but the valve started leaking when I turned the water back on. There looks to be a black ring inside the valve. Could that have been left behind by the previous stem? Should I pull it out? I don’t know what supposed to be inside the valve. However, the stem I pulled out does not have one, while the plastic one does.


That black ring is a seal and left over from previous stem.
You can not seal it with two rings on top of each other.
Take the old one out carefully not to scratch the valve surface inside and use only one ring.
